# Does anyone have any creative ideas to be able to connect and disconnect through-hole board to board headers with only one side soldered?

Tags: connector, header

We are looking for an inexpensive part with several sources to easily connect two boards together with around 20 signals. We are looking to use two of these headers since there are several sources and they are inexpensive. The only issue is we would need to be able to unplug and plug the boards back. We have a height constraint of 2.6mm so we would not be able to use a mating part for it to be pluggable. I have seen ones with kinked pins but those don't make enough connection alone and still need soldering. Does anyone know if there is a way to have only one end soldered and have something on the other board to keep the through hole pins attached but also remove them when needed (something like my primitive drawing below)? During production this is important for validation. We do have space on the side of the board where the pins get inserted through to add a socket to keep it in place if such a thing exist. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: A component that hold the pins in place]

Comment: Check this out: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/114. It probably needs some tries, but if the design is done properly, I'm pretty sure you can use this idea so that both boards connect and keep in place, without any soldering. That would be good for a very occasional connection, though. The via holes will probably become loose or degrade if you connect the board repetitively. Maybe the header will also bend after some time.

Answer (score 26):

Why do through all the trouble? Just get connectors that were intended for the purpose: mezzanine connectors. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/arrays-edge-type-mezzanine-board-to-board/308

For example [dual-beam connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=dual_beam_b2b_conn) (my site).

[image: Hirose BM 46]

{Hirose}

The cost of these SMD connector is less than the cost of the labor to solder the pins of those pin strip headers.

Comment: Also, the specific type you show has multiple companies offering near identical parts, so that fulfills the multi-source criterion

Comment: If you are not afraid to depend on AliBaba, they have tons of cheap ones.

Comment: Those Hirose connectors are $0.20/ea for 1000 which is extremely expensive in the context of consumer electronics. You can get 0.1" headers wave soldered for a lot less. Chinese mezzanine connectors are more reasonable at $0.03/ea

Answer (score 15):

You can get surface mount through hole female connectors: I've seen them on the Raspberry Pi TV hat.  It's surface mount, on top, with holes for the connector of the Pi to come through from the bottom.  Obviously you could mount it on the bottom of the top board.

I understand they're made by Samtec.  Height is 3.66mm above/below the board.  I believe they make smaller varieties, basically similar but higher density and lower profile.

[image]
From [Rapsberry Pi Org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2018/10/770A9390-1-1610x1080.jpg)

Comment: Works - but can eat loads of space on your board

Comment: Perhaps, though it does seem to be pretty much exactly what the question made a drawing of.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the room for some screw holes (and standoffs) or latching hardware, consider pogo pin or spring array contacts.  These can be extremely low profile and are commonly used in cell phones for things like antennas on the removable backshell (or, they did, back when replaceable batteries were the style, anyway..).  Examples: 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/823-22-006-10-000101/1146866 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kyocera-avx/009155004002016/1687155 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samtec-inc/SIB-107-02-F-S-LC/6693961

Comment: Or just a fixture that looks like a waffle maker

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use a "PC Pin Receptacle" type socket.  Alignment is probably going to be a pain but I don't think you'll be able to find something with less height on the mating side of the board.  (Edit: @jonathanjo did!)

[image: Mill-Max 0355-0-15-01-02-01-10-0]

(Image from Mill-Max)

Comment: The in-board sockets may be tough to fit on pitch, but they also make them with pin tails which will fit an ordinary header footprint. Mill-Max (and others) also make low-profile headers, usually with machined spring sockets like above, and round machined, or square pins.